# ImmutableJs - How to Retrieve Key Based On Position in Map

Tags: javascript, loops, key, immutable.js

Im using [immutableJs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js)

My state object looks like this:

```
export const initialToolbarState = Map({
    temSelectionCtrl : Map({
        temSelect : true,
    }),
    functionalCtrl : Map({
        addEle : true,
        grpSelect : true,
        drawShape : true
    }),
    operationalCtrl : Map({
        zoomIn : true,
         zoomOut : true,
         pan : true,
         temSide : true
    }),
    referenceCtrl : Map({
        saveCtrl : true
    })
});
```

So there are objects with keys which have `boolean` values.

I want to map (loop) over these objects & get their `keys`. The `boolean` values tell whether to render the `key` or not. Immutable lets us map over `Map`s using its custom `map` function. So, the following works, however not as intended:

```
// map over the initialToolbarState Map object 
let ctrls = initialToolbarState.map(( eachToolbar ) => {
  // map over the child Map objects like temSelectionCtrl, functionalCtrl, operationalCtrl etc
  return eachToolbar.map(( eachCtrl, i ) => {
    // get the key corresponding to 'eachCtrl' value
    let propKey = eachToolbar.keyOf( eachCtrl );
      // propKey is always the first property (1st prop) of 'eachToolbar'
        console.log( propKey );
...
```

Using `immutableJs`, is there a way to get the correct `key` corresponding to the currect 'eachCtrl' value within the loop? Could I make sure of the `i` to help pointing it towards the correct `value` for which to match the `key`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` again on your objects. The second argument is the key, with the full argument signature being `(mapper (value: V, key: K, iter: this))`

So, this snippet:

```
initialToolbarState.map(( eachToolbar ) => {
  eachToolbar.map((value, key) => {
    console.log(key, ' ==> ', value);
  });
});
```

Will log:

```
temSelect  ==>  true
addEle  ==>  true
grpSelect  ==>  true
drawShape  ==>  true
// etc…
```

Now just chain your returns to create the data structure that you need or do whatever with your keys.

Also, reconsider if this *“Map of Maps”* is the best structure for the problems you are solving. Perhaps a *“List of Maps”* is better if you need to iterate often. You won’t have instant read/update for individual items, but if your list consists of only a couple of items, then the performance will not suffer.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply. I ended up restructuring as I dont think that structure was flexible enough. Thanks again!